# How can I get and add elements from json file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example, let's say I have a JSON file like this.

```
const rooms = {
  livingroom: {
    "tv":true,
    "laptop": true,
    "air-conditioner":true,
  },
  kitchen: {
    "fridge":true,
    "dining-table": true,
  },
  gameroom: {
    "computer":true,
    "headphones":true,
    "microphone":true,
    "cd-player":true,
  }
}
```

This is my example project. What I'm trying to do is-

I want to be able to get items based on the room name, and show which items it has, "computer", "microphone" etc.
But I want to add new room name, and new items...

What can i do to achieve something like this in React Native?

Comment: I'd probably ask you a bit more context to your issue, like where is the file stored do you get it from an API request or is it a physical file with .json extension inside your project folder, depending of the cases there are different solutions

Comment: its a file in the project in react native. A bit more detail of what i want is i will have a button, lets say addRoomButton, and when i press on button, it will open a page which has some items toggled off. I will be able to toggle on that items. And items which i toggled on, should be added rooms.data, so i want to see it in my related screen. Is it easy?

Comment: when i press on button, there will be a text which i will write room name, other item part will be toggled off which ill be able to toggle on, to add to the room property

Answer (score 0):

This is not a json file this is a js file with an object called rooms.

To add a room to the object do the fallowing:

```
rooms[<new room name>] = { <Key:value pairs>}
```

for example:

```
rooms["study"] = { "chair":true, "table":true}
```

To add an item do the same with the item name and the value:

```
rooms["study"]["chair"] = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can i do that only by pressing on a button? For example i want to press on a button (addRoomButton) and there will be some items (toggled off), and i can do toggle on by clicking, is it easy to add those items in rooms . data ?

Comment: you can convert rooms into a state and have the button's onPress set the state

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Data.js` file and then use it in another file like this

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/use-files)

`Data.js` should look like this -

```
const rooms = {
  livingroom: {
    tv: true,
    laptop: true,
    'air-conditioner': true,
  },
  kitchen: {
    fridge: true,
    'dining-table': true,
  },
  gameroom: {
    computer: true,
    headphones: true,
    microphone: true,
    'cd-player': true,
  },
};

export default rooms;
```

`App.js` should look like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import Data from './Data';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{Data.gameroom.computer.toString()}</Text>
      <Text>{Data.kitchen.fridge.toString()}</Text>
      <Text>{Data.livingroom.laptop.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Well i dont want to add room and items by hand. I mean i will have a button, lets say addRoomButton, and when i press on button, it will open a page which has some items toggled off. I will be able to toggle on that items. 
And items which i toggled on, should be added rooms.data, so i want to see it in my related screen. Is it easy?